# Queen - We are the champions (Present Perfect)

Tags: present-perfect

French L1 speaker here.

I have a few questions related to the use of the present perfect and the simple past in this song. Would someone be so kind as to explain why certain verbs are in the simple past?

1)
I've done my sentence
But **committed** no crime.

Q1. Why isn't it "but I'**ve committed** no crime?" After all, the time is unspecified. What am I missing?

2)
I've had my share of sand **kicked** in my face

Q2. Same question here. Why not "I've had my share of sand that **has been kicked** in my face?"

3)
You **brought** me fame and fortune, and everything that goes with it.

Q3. Why not "You'**ve brought** me fame and fortune?". Here, I'm guessing it's because the individuals aren't going to bring him fame and fortune anymore. (finished action) Am I correct?

4)
Unrelated Bonus question

And we'**ll** keep on fighting 'til the end.

Q. Why not "And we'**re gonna** keep on fighting 'til the end?" After all, "going to" is used for plans related to the future. While "will" is for when someone makes a decision on the spot.

Thank you for helping me better understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no requirement to repeat the auxiliary verb when the verb phrase contains more than one lexical verb joined as these verbs are by **and**.

> I'**ve** tidied my room and [I've] washed the windows.

2. **kicked in my face**  is a participle clause.  **kicked** is not tensed but expresses  a state or condition of  **sand**.

Compare:

> I like food **cooked in oil** and food **cooked on a grill**

Another way of understanding **kicked in my face** is that it is a special kind of complement modifying the object of the verb **had**:

> I have had [I have experienced] sand <sup>object</sup> {kicked in my
>   face}.

But it's really no different from:

> I have eaten food **cooked on a grill**.

But in either analysis **kicked** is not tensed. The phrase pertains either to **sand** alone or to **sand** as object of the verb.

3. You **brought** me fame.

I have never looked at the lyrics of that song carefully, but I would suppose that this sentence is describing something that happened in the past, not the current status of the speaker.  Although the fame might persist to the present moment,  the becoming-famous, the being-made-famous, happened in the past.

4. Your understanding of **will** is too rigid and limited.
   **We're gonna** is an approximation of how "we're going to" is pronounced in normal colloquial speech where the speaker is not trying to articulate the words  according to how they're spelled. **We're going to** and **we will** are two equally viable ways of forming a statement about an intention to do something in the future.

Comment: Your explanation is quite clear for question one. However, you are using **and**. Would this also be true for **but** as is the case in the song?

Comment: Although this would not be ungrammatical: *I've tidied my room but not washed the windows.*  it would be more common to hear (at least in my experience as a speaker of AmE): *I've tidied my room but **haven't** washed the windows.*

Comment: I see. So, the equivalent for the lyrics using *standard* grammar would be "I've done my sentence but not committed any crime." As per your prior explanation, this would be grammatical but not your favorite structure to use. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Further to differences involving the ***and / but*** choice, *I like food cooked in oil **and** on a grill* (eliding implicitly repeated *cooked*) sounds awkward to me, but I've no quarrel with *I like food cooked in oil **or** on a grill*.

Comment: First, a couple of caveats: **favorite** isn't the appropriate term as these choices are not deliberate ones; it would be better to refer to the choice as "most likely to be used";  second, judging song lyrics by the grammatical rules that apply to formal writing or even to informal conversation is always dubious. In my neck of the woods, we would say, in conversation, "I've done my sentence but **didn't commit** any crime." or *I've done my sentence but haven't committed any crime.* Not likely to be heard is *I've done my sentence but not committed any crime.*

Comment: **... but committed no crime** is not really in informal conversational register in AmE in the year 2018.  It is perfectly grammatical, just not casual.  I've seen it called an "archaic negative" though I would disagree with that characterization.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarifications. However, your latest comments have muddied my understanding of your answer to question 1. "I've done my sentence but didn't commit any crime." Why would you use the simple past if the time is unspecified?

Comment: The absence of a specific past time reference does not make the simple past impossible. Rather, the presence of a specific past time reference makes the simple past mandatory. *I **ate** fish **yesterday*** versus   *I feel nauseated. I **did eat** those leftovers.*